# MongoDB journaling enabled?

Tags: bash, mongodb, journaling

I want to find out if MongoDB journaling is enabled with a bash script.

Can I do that some other way than searching the config files, because that is not very reliable, I think.

Is `mongo --eval "something"` possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, as long as you can parse a JSON document that `mongo --eval "db.serverStatus()"` returns. Depending on which storage engine your server is configured, you may be interested in [wiredTiger.log](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/serverStatus/#dur-journaling) or [dur](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/serverStatus/#dur-journaling) field of the returned document. If journaling is turned off then values of all fields in wiredTiger.log are "0" or dur is absent altogether. (Also see [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-journaling/#monitor-journal-status))

Comment: Note that `dur` is for the MMAPv1 storage engine, which is deprecated as of mongoDB 4.0